# Find the values of $x$ for which the following function has horizontal tangents:

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function is $8x^3 - 6x$

I tried using the chain rule, but got stuck because this function has no “inside”. I tried expanding to see if that would do anything, but that also didn’t help.

How would you solve this?

Comment: You don't need the chain rule.  It's just a polynomial.  The derivative is $24x^2-6$

Comment: Expanding what ? What was your goal doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

$y = 8x^3 - 6x$

As horizontal tangents will have a slope of zero, equate the derivative to $0$ to find the horizontal tangents, $\frac{dy}{dx} = 24x^2 - 6 = 0 \implies x = \pm\frac{1}{2}$

That gives two tangents $y = \mp 2$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thanks for reversing the sign.